# TeleBot. Создание клавиатуры

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Использую библиотеку `pyTelegramBotAPI`.

В телеботе прописаны несколько команд для вывода информации в группу\чат.

Появился вопрос, как можно реализовать кнопки для выполнения этих команд?

Т.е. при отправке сообщения "Список" или команды /Список - выводятся несколько кнопок с готовыми командами, при нажатии на которые будет выполнена та или иная функция.

Comment: Хоть ЯП укажи..

Comment: Python. Я думал телебот только на питоне. Хм хм.

Comment: Первые ссылки гугла показывают telebot на javascript: https://github.com/mullwar/telebot :D